# Learning Lisp and artificial intelligence

Tags: lisp, artificial-intelligence

This semester at college I have a course for Artificial Intelligence and we are studying Lisp.  The problem is that I don't have any functional programming background, but I do know OOP programming (Java, Javascript, PHP).

Can you recommend some good books to get me up to speed on Lisp and artificial intelligence?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this question:

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-grasp-functional-programming-concepts

Comment: Lisp is not about functional or object oriented programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (3rd Edition)

The Little Schemer - 4th Edition

Let Over Lambda—50 Years of Lisp

and there is much more recent C++(boost, melt, blitz++, functional c++,.. etc).

--
BTW, RIP dmr, Thanks.

Comment: LOL is great, but not really for a beginner, IMO. The other LOL, Land of Lisp, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

These I have found helpful and pretty approachable:

1. Practical Common Lisp - Peter Seibel
2. ANSI Common LISP - Paul Graham

Comment: You can read the whole of Practical Common Lisp here, although I recommend buying a paper copy if you like it: http://gigamonkeys.com/book/

Answer (score 3):

Not to forget the classic ["Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming: Case Studies in Common Lisp"](http://norvig.com/paip.html) by Peter Norvig. Especially his coding style is very clear and a pleasure to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few:

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lisp+programming+artificial+intelligence&x=0&y=0

I hear this one is really good, too:

[http://www.amazon.com/Lisp-3rd-Patrick-Winston/dp/0201083191/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1318507734&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201083191)

I've never read it myself.

This is a good book for coming up to speed on Lisp:

[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Common-Lisp-Peter-Seibel/dp/1590592395/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318507782&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592395)